# New to coding and i'm building a text-based game. Not sure what my issue is

Tags: python

The game works fine, except im trying to add a restart function where the game restarts when a user inputs restart into any input. Here is my code, not sure what the issue is.

```
# Scoring Elements #
incorrect = 0

# Key Variables #
reset = True
tutorial_input = ""
input1 = ""
input2 = ""
input3 = ""
input4a = ""
input4b = ""
input5 = ""
input6a = ""
input6b = ""
input6c = ""
input7a = ""
input7b = ""
input8wel = ""
input8a = ""
input8b = ""
input8c = ""
input9 = ""

def reset_check():
    global tutorial_input, input1, input2, input3, input4a, input4b, input5, input6a, input6b, input6c, input7a, input7b, input8wel, input8a, input8b, input8c, input9, reset
    if (
        tutorial_input.lower() == "restart" or
        input1.lower() == "restart" or
        input2.lower() == "restart" or
        input3.lower() == "restart" or
        input4a.lower() == "restart" or
        input4b.lower() == "restart" or
        input5.lower() == "restart" or
        input6a.lower() == "restart" or
        input6b.lower() == "restart" or
        input6c.lower() == "restart" or
        input7a.lower() == "restart" or
        input7b.lower() == "restart" or
        input8wel.lower() == "restart" or
        input8a.lower() == "restart" or
        input8b.lower() == "restart" or
        input8c.lower() == "restart" or
        input9.lower() == "restart"
    ):
        reset = True

# Welcome #
while reset:
    reset = False
    print("Welcome to the Every Dew Challenge. Solve each puzzle to pass the Guardians")
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    print("Welcome aboard " +name+", good luck!")
    reset = 1

    # Restart Function #
    print(''' 
If at anytime during the game you want to restart, input RESTART and the game will restart
''')

    # Tutorial #
    print("Be silent to continue.")
    tutorial_input = input("")
    reset_check()

    while tutorial_input != "" :
        print("Shh....")
        incorrect += 1
        tutorial_input = input("")
        reset_check()

    else :
        print("You may pass")

    # level 1 #

    print('''
    ----- Level 1 -----
     ''')


    print("I'm the Guardian, say my name to pass")
    input1 = input("")
    reset_check()

    while input1 != "my name" :
        print("Say my name to pass")
        incorrect += 1
        input1 = input("")
        reset_check()

    else :
        print("You may pass")

    # Level 2 #
    print('''
    ----- Level 2 -----
     ''')

    print("Two digits are needed - first and last.")
    input2 = input("")
    reset_check()

    while input2 != "23" :
        if input2 == "first" :
            print("a couple...")
            input2 = input("")
            reset_check()

        elif input2 == "last":
            print("this many is a crowd...")
            input2 = input("")
            reset_check()

        else :
            print("first and last")
            incorrect += 1
            input2 = input("")
            reset_check()

    else :
        print("You may pass")

    # Level 3 #
    print('''
    ----- Level 3 -----
     ''')

    print("shout the answer to pass.")
    input3 = input("")
    reset_check()

    while input3 != "THE ANSWER":
        print("You have to SHOUT the answer.")
        incorrect += 1
        input3 = input("")
        reset_check()

    else :
        print("You may pass")

    # Level 4 #
    print('''
    ----- Level 4 -----
     ''')

    verdict = 0
    print("Knock knock...")
    input4a = input("")
    reset_check()


    while verdict == 0 :
        if input4a == "who's there" :
                print("You!")
                input4b = input("")
                reset_check()

                if input4b == name :
                    print("You may pass.")
                    verdict = 1

                elif input4b != name :
                    print("Knock knock...")
                    incorrect += 1
                    input4a = input("")
                    reset_check()

        elif input4a != "who's there":
            print("Knock knock...")
            incorrect += 1
            input4a = input("")
            reset_check()

    # Level 5 #
    print('''
    ----- Level 5 -----
     ''')
    print("Say something 3 times in a row.")
    counter = 0
    input5 = input("")
    reset_check()

    while counter < 3 :

        if input5 != "something" :
            counter = 0
            print("Say something 3 times in a row.")
            incorrect += 1
            input5 = input("")
            reset_check()

        elif input5 == "something" :
            counter = counter + 1

            if counter == 3:
                print("You may pass")

            else:
                input5 = input("")
                reset_check()

    # Level 6 #
    print('''
    ----- Level 6 -----
     ''')

    passed = "false"
    print("What ends everyone?")
    input6a = input("")
    reset_check()


    while passed == "false":
        if input6a == "death" :
            print("...and that links to?")
            input6b = input("")
            reset_check()

            while input6b != "honey" :
                incorrect += 1
                print("death links to...")
                input6b = input("")
                reset_check()

            else:
                print("you may pass")
                passed = "true"

        elif input6a == "e" :
            print("...and that links to?")
            input6c = input("")
            reset_check()

            while input6c != "elephant" :
                print("e links to...")
                incorrect += 1
                input6c = input("")
                reset_check()

            else :
                print("you may pass")
                passed = "true"

        else :
            print("What ends everyone?")
            incorrect += 1
            input6a = input("")
            reset_check()



    # Level 7 #
    print(
        """
    ----- Level 7 -----
     """
    )

    passed = "false"
    print("Are you happy or sad?")
    input7a = input("")
    reset_check()

    while passed == "false":
        if input7a == "happy":
            print("0b00011111011000000000")
            input7b = input("")
            reset_check()

            while input7b != ":)":
                print("Show me your smile")
                incorrect += 1
                input7b = input("")
                reset_check()
            else:
                print(chr(0b00011111011000000000))
                passed = "true"
                print("You may pass")

        elif input7a == "sad":
            print("0b00011111011000010100")
            input7c = input("")
            reset_check()

            while input7c != ":(":
                print("Show me your frown")
                incorrect += 1
                input7c = input("")
                reset_check()
            else:
                print(chr(0b00011111011000010100))
                passed = "true"
                print("You may pass")
        else:
            print("Are you happy or sad?")
            incorrect += 1
            input7a = input("")
            reset_check()



    #Level 8 - My First Custom Level #
    print('''
    ----- Level 8 -----
    ''')

    lives = 3
    level = 1



    print("Finish the lyrics to these 3 famous songs, get them wrong and face the consequences.")
    print(str(lives) + " Lives remaining.")
    input8wel = input(" -- Press Enter to begin -- ")
    reset_check()



    def check():
        global lives, level, incorrect
        if lives <= 0:
            print("You Have Run Out of Lives!")
            lives = 3
            level = 1
            incorrect += 1
            input8wel = input(" -- Press Enter to try again -- ")
            reset_check()


    while True:

        if level == 1:
            print("Level 1 - Happy birthday to ___ ")
            input8a = input("")
            reset_check()
            
            if input8a.lower() != "you":
                print("Wrong! Lose a life")
                lives -= 1
                check()
                print(str(lives) + " lives remaining.")

            else:
                print("Correct! On to Level 2")
                level = 2


        elif level == 2:
            print("Level 2 - To Advance Australia ____ ")
            input8b = input("")
            reset_check()
            
            if input8b.lower() != "fair":
                print("Wrong! Lose a life")
                lives -= 1
                check()
                print(str(lives) + " lives remaining.")

            else:
                print("Correct! On to Level 3")
                level = 3

        elif level == 3:
            print("Level 3 - God save the ____ ")
            input8c = input("")
            reset_check()
            
            if input8c.lower() != "king":
                print("Wrong! Lose a life")
                lives -= 1
                check()
                print(str(lives) + " lives remaining.")

            else:
                break

    print("Correct! You may pass")


    # Level 9 - My Second Custom Level #

    print('''
    ----- Level 9 -----
     ''')

    print('''This is the final level and will require some creative thinking.
    ''')
    print('''The clues for this level are as follows:
        1. Do not input the same answer twice
        2. Only one answer is correct
        3. Go make your attempts quickly. Time is running out!

    The answer is an animal.''')

    input9 = input("What am I? ")
    reset_check()

    while input9.lower() != "dog":
        print("LOOK at the clues. The answer is staring at you!")
        incorrect += 1
        input9 = input("")
        reset_check()

    else :
        print("You have finished the game! Congratulations!")
        print("In total, you made "+str(incorrect)+" errors. That's not too bad!")
```

I've tried using ChatGPT but not much help. Any help would be appreciated, just not sure what my issue is here. To me it seems correct but the reset_check() function doesn't work.

Comment: What makes you think that the `reset_check` function doesn't work?

Comment: when I input "restart" nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Your `while reset:` line is not evaluated at each call (or return) of `reset_check()`, which is why your program is not resetting. You will need to determine some way to break out of the loop and re-evaluate, or a different method of iterating through your many challenges, such that the `while reset:` condition is evaluated (and acted upon if required) each time.